# Does Blackthorne's 4-piece set bonus prevent fury gain from molten, plagued, and desecrator?

Tags: diablo-iii

As a Barbarian with decent damage reduction gear, I often park myself directly in molten, plague, and desecration fields so that my [Superstition](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/passive/superstition) passive kicks in and fills my fury bar quickly. Sometimes it's so good I can just spam Hammer of the Ancients and never run out of fury. All that spent fury, combined with [Bloodthirst](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/passive/bloodthirst), means I'm typically healing through the damage safely. I can kill elite packs with these affixes considerably faster (and more safely) than those without due to all the extra fury.

However, I'm considering moving up in Torment where the damage from those fields will be more significant and am looking for ways to mitigate it. I'm considering working on a [Blackthorne's set](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/blackthornes-jousting-mail) for the 4-piece bonus of "*You are immune to Desecrator, Molten, and Plagued monster ground effects.*" However, I'm wondering if this will prevent those fields from generating fury from the effects, since I won't be receiving damage from them. Reading the wording of the two things logically, it seems like it wouldn't work, but it certainly wouldn't be the first time in Diablo 3 that the actual mechanics of how a thing works differ from the describing text.

So, if the Blackthorne set gives me immunity to molten, plagued, and descrator, does it also prevent fury generation from those same effects?

Comment: For it to do what is intended, you need to be actually taking non-physical damage (ranged or elemental, which you won't be taking from those sources) to get the reduced damage and fury generation effect.

Comment: I think Krazer is right, you certainly don't get fury if you wear Countess Julia and camp out in arcane beams, BTs probably work the same way, you just won't take any damage but you won't gain fury.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Krazer and z ' are right, it will prevent fury generation from these damage sources since you won't be taking any damage :)